# Can I access variables, methods of an Activity Class from a Non-Activity-Class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, access-modifiers

I want to operate some functionality of my activity class from another class. Because my the number of codes in activity class is increasing and difficult to understand later.

This is the activity class

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int number = 7;
    public String name = "arafat";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        printSomething();
    }

    private void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

and here is the non-activity class

NonActivityClass.java

```
public class NonActivityClass {
    //can I access the variables and methods from here
}
```

How can I will be able to access the global or private fields of activity class from this non-activity class?

Comment: Any variables that it needs to access should be passed in, and should to the greatest degree possible be treated as immutable unless you have very good reason not to.  Classes accessing each others variables directly is generally considered a very bad idea.  And the fact you're confusing the idea with inheritance shows that you don't really understand OOP yet and should probably spend more effort on that.

Comment: You may need to read more about **OOP** and **static** keyword.

Comment: I have solved this in that way :

 import android.util.Log;
Is the any other way
public class NonActivityClass {
    //can I access the variables and methods from here
    private static final String TAG = "NonActivityClass";

    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public NonActivityClass(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivity = activity;
    }
    String name;
    public void doSomething() {
        name = mainActivity.name;
        Log.d(TAG, "doSomething: " + name);
    }
} 

But are there any other ways for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem,use oop concept and static keyword

I have use one java class and one Activity.I have create Java class object in Activity to call and access class methods and variables like this

**This is my code:**

```
public class NonActivityClass {
 String Myname = "demo";
static String  Myfullname = "";

public static void setName(String name) {
    Myfullname = name;
}

public  String getName() {
    Log.e("check_value","working");
}
public static String getFullName() {
    return Myfullname;
}
}
```

In this class i have create some static or not static variable and some method like getname(),setname()and getFullname();

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;

 import static com.example.rdprojects.NonActivityClass.Myfullname;
 import static com.example.rdprojects.NonActivityClass.getFullName;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //create NonActivityClass object
    NonActivityClass myclass = new NonActivityClass();

       myclass.getName();

    //call static variable
    Myfullname = "demo demo";
    String fullname = getFullName();

    Log.e("check_full_name", "" + fullname);

}


}
```

In this activity first of all i have create java class object and use this object to call variable and method . and some static method call directly .
if you try to get data form any java class to in activity try this code.

Comment: I want to access the fields of activity class from non-activity class. You have done a reverse process here.

Comment: Yes we do this make static variables and methods in main activity which you want to access in non-activity class.